# Delphi XE10 How to marshal a TPicture

Tags: delphi, marshalling, datasnap

I'm trying to write a marshaller for a TPicture so that I can send objects classes containing a TPicture though datasnap methods. 
I'm having difficulties finding an appropriate way of doing that, I have tried to send TMemoryStream as TObject but it appears that the "data from the picture is lost". I have tried to put the picture into a string - but that would, I guess, give me all kind's of troubles putting binary data into a string.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to marshal TPicture properly?

Here's what I'm doing, so far it looks like I get the picture into the result tobject, but I get a leak since I create an instance of the PictureMarshal class.
Don't mind the FChildren, that works fine.

```
type
  TPictureMarshall = class
    FPictureName : string;
    FPictureSize : Integer;
    FPictureData : TBytes;
  end;

 TPersonMar = class(TObject)

 private
   FStringList : TStringList; // complex object that needs marshalling
   FChildren: array of TPerson; // complex object that needs marshalling
   FMar : TJsonMarshal;
   FPicture : TPicture;
   procedure RegisterConverters;
   procedure SetStringlist(const Value: TStringList);
 public
   function Marshal : string;  // should handle marshalling
   property Stringlist : TStringList read FStringlist write SetStringlist;
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
   procedure AddChild(AKid: TPerson);
 end;



procedure TPersonMar.RegisterConverters;
begin
    FMar.RegisterConverter(ClassType, 'FPicture', function(Data: TObject; Field: String): TObject
    var
      AMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
      APic : TPictureMarshall;

    begin
       AMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         result := TPictureMarshall.Create; // but who frees this?
         FPicture.Graphic.SaveToStream(AMemoryStream);
         TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureName := 'Somepicturefilename.png';
         TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureSize := AMemoryStream.Size;
         SetLength(TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureData, TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureSize);
         ZeroMemory(TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureData, TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureSize);

         AMemoryStream.Position := 0; // reset position
         AMemoryStream.ReadBuffer(TPictureMarshall(Result).FPictureData, AMemoryStream.Size);
       finally
         AMemoryStream.Free;
       end;

    end);
end;







"FMar":null,"FPicture":{"type":"TestObjU.TPictureMarshall","id":14,"fields":{"FPictureName":"Somepicturefilename.png","FPictureSize":71290,"FPictureData":[137,80,78,71,13,...snip]}}}}
```

Comment: Can't you save the image to a stream and send it as binary? Does datasnap support binary? Otherwise you'd save to stream and base64 encode it. FWIW, `SetLength` zero initialises memory. No point in you doing it again. And there's no point in zeroising that memory anyway since you immediately write of it with a call to `ReadBuffer`.

Comment: Well, yes, it's possible to send a TStream as parameter in a servermethod from the client to the server and also possible to retreive a stream from the server.
Thats in fact the solution (workaround I'm currently using), however I would like to have a base class which can marshall and unmarshall e.g. TPicture so I can send the objects simply by adding it to the parameters of the method.

This is what I do now, of course if it's not possible to find another way then that it.

    function TServerMethods1.UpdatePerson(APerson : TPerson; APictureStream: TMemoryStream) : Boolean;

Comment: Does datasnap really send binary by encoding each byte as a decimal string? The perf for that must suck!

Comment: I know the **zeromemory** is not needed, just part of my trial and error to make sure I don't see uninitialised memory.

Comment: You won't see uninitialized error. The `ReadBuffer` sees to that. As it stands, you zeroise the memory twice.

Comment: Honestly I don't know - the marshaller above is my faulty invention, wouldn't blame datasnap for that :)
Sending a TStream as parameter works, and may be that'll be some string/bytes representation in the JSON world down below the surface.